# Remove image border

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the image border, I have tried the following method

```
img {
    border: 0px;
}
```

Also I tried the following from the console of the browser `border: none !important`

my html code is

```
<div id="startDiv" style="font-size: 40;margin-left: 166px;margin-top: 207px" >
  <img onclick="startApplet();" id="start" />
</div>
```

I write the following inside style tag in head

```
#start {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(images/start.png) 0 150px;
    border-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle? - I cant see any reason for there being a border

Comment: *sidenote:* 0 has no unit in CSS. no need to add `px` after `0`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#start img{
    border:none!important;
    border-style:none;
}
```

Comment: just `border: none` is fine .

Comment: I fixed the problem...problem is with the img tag...i replaced the img tag with div ....and that worked fine